# Is the C# docs about input value of hyperbolic functions (Math.Sinh, Math.Cosh, Math.Tanh) wrong?

Tags: c#, math

The docs of [Math.Sinh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sinh?view=net-5.0), [Math.Cosh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.cosh?view=net-5.0), [Math.Tanh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.tanh?view=net-5.0) all says:

> Parameters
>
> `value`
> Double
>
> An angle, measured in radians.

> Remarks
>
> The angle, value, must be in radians. Multiply by Math.PI/180 to
> convert degrees to radians.
>
> This method calls into the underlying C runtime, and the exact result
> or valid input range may differ between different operating systems or
> architectures.

The input value is obviously not an angle, but the [area](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803102/what-are-hyperbolic-trig-functions-functions-of) (which means it doesn't effect if the angle is measured in Degrees or Radians or Gradians).

So is it a "copy-paste" mistake of Microsoft docs?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_angle

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I have tested it on Microsoft Calculator, the result of Sinh/Cosh/Tanh isn't effected by the Angle Unit (Degrees, Radians, Grads).

Also, according to Wikipedia:

[image]

> point (**cosh a**, **sinh a**), where **a** is **twice the area** between the ray

Of course it's a mistake of the docs of Microsoft.